# How to mass / bulk PutObjectAcl in Amazon S3?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, acl

I am looking for a way to update several objects ACL in one (of few request) to the AWS API.

My web application contains several sensitive objects stored in AWS S3. This object have a default ACL to "private". I sometimes need to update several objects ACL to "public-read" for some time (a couple of minutes) before going back to "private".

For a couple of objects, one request per object to [PutObjectAcl](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/API_PutObjectAcl.html) is ok. But when dealing with several objects (hundreds), the operation requires to much time.

My question is : how can I "mass put object acl" or "bulk put object acl" ? The AWS API doesn't contain a specific answer, like [DeleteObjects](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/API_DeleteObjects.html) (which allows to delete several objects at once). But may be I didn't look in the right place ?!

Any tricks or way to work around that would be of great value !

Comment: You are correct - there is not a bulk ACL operation. One workaround is to write a workflow that uses AWS Step functions where you can feed a list and run the workflow. That way - an app is not waiting for the job to be done.

Answer (score 2):

Mixing private and public objects inside a bucket is usually a bad idea. If you only need those objects to be public for a couple of minutes, you can create a [pre-signed GET URL](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/ShareObjectPreSignedURL.html) and set a desired expiration time.

Comment: Agreed. You should _never_ "update several objects ACL to "public-read" for some time". This is exactly what **Pre-Signed URLs** are designed to solve.

Comment: I get your point. very interesting... I use this AWS S3 functionnality to creat download temporary links. That unfortunately still leaves the problem of doing it in bulk...

Comment: @call_me_Vlad The process of creating a temporary pre-signed url doesn't involve contacting the s3 server. It's all done locally, so you can create them in bulk using a a loop.